# Show/Hide Multiple Divs angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to use some Li list to show/hide multiple divs angular2.

The page will initially show all divs. when the small screen i hide some div in In small screen when i click list 1 how to show the particular Div

```
<li><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(1)"></i>Locator</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(2)"></i>Offer</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(3)"></i> Contact</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(4)"></i>Holiday</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(4)"></i>FAQ</li>

<div id="div1" *ngIf="windowWidth > 767">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div2" *ngIf="windowWidth > 767">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div3" *ngIf="windowWidth > 767">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div4" *ngIf="windowWidth > 767">Lorum Ipsum</div>
```

file.ts:

```
windowWidth: number = window.innerWidth;

  //initial values, The window object may still be undefined during this hook, let me know if that's the case and we'll figure out a better hook for the initial value
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  //if screen size changes it'll update
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  resize(event) {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class MyComponent {
  selectedIndex = -1;

  showDiv(index) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }
}
```

```
<li><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(1)"></i>Locator</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(2)"></i>Offer</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(3)"></i> Contact</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(4)"></i>Holiday</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" (click)="showDiv(4)"></i>FAQ</li>

<div id="div1" *ngIf="windowWidth > 767 && selectedIndex === 1">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div2" *ngIf="windowWidth > 767 && selectedIndex === 2">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div3" *ngIf="windowWidth > 767 && selectedIndex === 3">Lorum Ipsum</div>
<div id="div4" *ngIf="windowWidth > 767 && selectedIndex === 4">Lorum Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: ok after hide how can i show particular Div when i click event? like http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to show/hide a single `div`, `ng-container` is no help.